# Alternativa a Matisse

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, matisse

Muy buenas. Estoy buscando una manera de crear formularios que contengan JLabel,JTextField, JButton, es decir, para registrar los datos de una persona o buscar en un JTable.

He estado trabajando hasta ahora con la GUI de NetBeans pero mi programa está haciéndose muy grande y me estoy dando cuenta que mi programa consume mucha memoria y eso a la larga no es bueno.

Ahora lo estoy haciendo los formularios a código pero colocar los componentes exactamente donde uno desea es costoso y lleva muchas lineas de código para pequeños resultados.

¿Conocéis alguna otra manera que se pueda crear un formulario de manera mas rápida y que no cargue tanto la memoria como hace NetBeans?

El proyecto ya se comenzó en NetBeans y está muy avanzado y cambiar el IDE ahora podría llevarnos mas quebraderos de cabeza que otra cosa, por lo que sería ideal que la alternativa funcionara también en NetBeans.

Muchas gracias por todo y un saludo.

Comment: Prueba usando eclipse con el plugin window builder, te genera GUI's más limpias.

Comment: Ya lo habia visto, el problema es que en el trabajo no puedo cambiar al Eclipse porque el proyecto ya se comenzó en NetBeans y está muy avanzado y cambiar el IDE ahora podría llevarnos mas quebraderos de cabeza que otra cosa.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que el problema del consumo de memoria nada tiene que ver con el código que genera NetBeans cuando crear interfaces gráficas. Aunque actualmente no uso SWING para desarrollos nuevos (ahora solo JavaFX), tengo aún un proyecto que mantengo muy grande y está desarrollado con la herramienta para GUI de NetBeans. Lo dicho, tu problema de memora no radica aquí. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No se si te sirva a la perfección, aunque debiste es:

1. Buscar GUI Builders en java.
2. Mirar proyectos de GitHub que puedan ser populares.
3. *Si nada de esto te sirve*, pues debes adaptarte a NetBeans.
4. Aún con lo de Eclipse, creo que lo importante sería revisar el código hecho de Eclipse y copiar lo esencial en NetBeans o viceversa.

He hallado otra, es gratis y deja ver la vista previa del código, espero te sirva:

Entra a http://guigenie.com/download/

Comment: Voy a probar el programa y ya te cuento, muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: De nada, recuerda que lo esencial en Java es buscar asi sea por paginas en Ingles (es dificil entender todo, aunque vale la pena :3), gracias Mauricio Arias por tu propuesta en mi respuesta :3, lamento ser novato en StackOverFlow

Comment: @AlexCoder, no hay problema y bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).